# JPQL can not prevent cache for JPQL query

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

Two (JSF + JPA + EclipseLink + MySQL) applications share the same database. One application runs a scheduled task where the other one creates tasks for schedules. The tasks created by the first application is collected by queries in the second one without any issue. The second application updates fields in the task, but the changes done by the second application is not refreshed when queried by JPQL.

I have added QueryHints.CACHE_USAGE as CacheUsage.DoNotCheckCache, still, the latest updates are not reflected in the query results.

The code is given below.

How can I get the latest updates done to the database from a JPQL query?

```
public List<T> findByJpql(String jpql, Map<String, Object> parameters, boolean withoutCache) {
    TypedQuery<T> qry = getEntityManager().createQuery(jpql, entityClass);
    Set s = parameters.entrySet();
    Iterator it = s.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        String pPara = (String) m.getKey();
        if (m.getValue() instanceof Date) {
            Date pVal = (Date) m.getValue();
            qry.setParameter(pPara, pVal, TemporalType.DATE);
        } else {
            Object pVal = (Object) m.getValue();
            qry.setParameter(pPara, pVal);
        }
    }
    if(withoutCache){
        qry.setHint(QueryHints.CACHE_USAGE, CacheUsage.DoNotCheckCache);
    }
    return qry.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CacheUsage settings affect what EclipseLink can query using what is in memory, but not what happens after it goes to the database for results.

It seems you don't want to out right avoid the cache, but refresh it I assume so the latest changes can be visible. This is a very common situation when multiple apps and levels of caching are involved, so there are many different solutions you might want to look into such as manual invalidation or even if both apps are JPA based, cache coordination (so one app can send an invalidation even to the other). Or you can control this on specific queries with the ["eclipselink.refresh"](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.0/org/eclipse/persistence/config/QueryHints.html#REFRESH) query hint, which will force the query to reload the data within the cached object with what is returned from the database. Please take care with it, as if used in a local EntityManager, any modified entities that would be returned by the query will also be refreshed and changes lost

References for caching:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching

https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/concepts/cache010.htm

Answer (score 1):

Make the Entity not to depend on cache by adding the following lines.

```
@Cache(
  type=CacheType.NONE, // Cache nothing
  expiry=0,
  alwaysRefresh=true
)
```

Comment: It gets the latest values from the database, yet I do not want no caching except for this query as there are performance issues.